# Creating a calendar event from within a plugin (stuck on saving)

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm trying to create an event from within a plugin. I've come up with the following:

```
$event = new Event(); // Solspace\Calendar\Elements\Event;
$event->authorId = 1;
$event->calendarId = 5;
$event->name = 'Hello name';
$event->title = 'Hello title';
$event->startDate = new DateTime();
$event->endDate = new DateTime();
$event->allDay = true;
```

But I don't understand how to actually save the event (e.g. `$event->save()`). Am I on the right track or completely off? I couldn't find anything on this in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got help on Discord. The way to do it was `Calendar::getInstance()->events->saveEvent($event);` Edit: `DateTime` also needs to be replaced with `Carbon()`